# How to Identify which person with root access has killed a job/process from a pool

Tags: linux, unix

I was curious to know if there are 3 or 4 people who has root access to a node. one of the person has initiated a job for running, But some one has killed the job that was running. what would be the best way to identify the person who killed the job/process because every body has root access.

Comment: Check with last command from which IP is logged the user in the time or killed process

Comment: Please don't create multiple posts on the SE network. Questions can be migrated if they need to be. You can flag your own question, check "needs moderator attension" and give the reason why you would like to migrate your question. Here is your question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30245298/816536

Answer (score 0):

Impossible without proper auditing enabled. Without auditing you can only guess based on timestamps on when exactly the job was killed (if you have such information) and which users were logged in. I guess they are logging in as normal users and using something like `su` or `sudo` to become root.

About auditing - basic would be to have a login script for root which would set a different history file based on who is switching to root. For more sophisticated auditing (kernel itself logging which user does what), google for "linux auditing".